# Python - google-cloud library - error in Google Cloud Shell

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to execute the following simple piece of python within Google Cloud Shell:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()

print(client)
```

I get the following error:

```
./test.py: line 2: $'\r': command not found
./test.py: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
'/test.py: line 3: `client = bigquery.Client()
```

Could someone please let me know what is it I'm doing wrong?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe you're using Windows line endings but you need to use Unix (`\n`)?

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Shell is a shell, not a Python REPL. You should type `python` first to enter the Python REPL, and then enter the Python calls you're trying to run. For example:

```
Welcome to Cloud Shell! Type "help" to get started.
Your Cloud Platform project in this session is set to my-project.
Use “gcloud config set project [PROJECT_ID]” to change to a different project.
dustiningram@cloudshell:~ (my-project)$ python
Python 2.7.13 (default, Nov 24 2017, 17:33:09)
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from google.cloud import bigquery
>>> client = bigquery.Client()
>>> print(client)
<google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client object at 0x7f86802b5050>
>>>
```